# How to set location of iframe created by external javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I am using external `javascript` to populate a popup when a page is loaded in my website. Like the below.

`<script type='text/javascript' src='https://www.website.com/some_website_javasciprt_filt'></script>`

The `javascript` above not only create a popup but also create a hidden `iframe`.

```
 pgmr_ifrm = document.createElement('iframe');
pgmr_ifrm.id = 'pg_merchrev_track';
pgmr_ifrm.style.position = 'absolute';
pgmr_ifrm.style.left = '1px';
pgmr_ifrm.style.visibility = 'hidden';
pgmr_ifrm.src='https://d2iz0h6pqiasve.cloudfront.net/images/spacer.gif';
body.insertBefore(pgmr_ifrm,bodyfirstchild);
```

The problem is that the `iframe` stays on webpage even though I close the popup and blocks my menu buttons.

Is it possible to set the position of the `iframe` after the page load so that it does not block my buttons?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried wrapping your code in $(document).ready(function() { });

Comment: It looks like you are appending the iframe to the document body. Shouldn't it be a child of your popup element ?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    pgmr_ifrm = document.createElement('iframe');
    pgmr_ifrm.id = 'pg_merchrev_track';
    pgmr_ifrm.style.position = 'absolute';
    pgmr_ifrm.style.left = '1px';
    pgmr_ifrm.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    pgmr_ifrm.src='https://d2iz0h6pqiasve.cloudfront.net/images/spacer.gif';
    body.insertBefore(pgmr_ifrm,bodyfirstchild);
});
```

This will do all the code after the page has loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I found much easier way of doing it.
Instead of dealing with `javascript`, I simply set the `z-index` in `CSS`.
Problem solved.